# Is there a way to do something similar to onbeforeunload for an AJAX form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript, onbeforeunload

Sadly, we are in a situation where we have to use a home-brew, spa-like engine, that hijacks all navigation and does it via `ajax`.

I am looking for a way to be able to add a tag to a `form`, maybe like this:

```
<form data-confirm-unsaved=""></form>
```

Which should cause a binding to the unloading of this `form`, whether it is an actual whole page unload (like someone closed the tab or typed in a URL) or a click on any of the hijacked navigation elements... but I do not want it to be triggered when the `form` is submitted/saved.

I have the beginning outline of what is NOT working code:

```
$('[data-confirm-unsaved]').on('beforeunload', function (e) {
        let isUnload = true;
        let message = $(this).attr('[data-confirm-unsaved]');
        if (message == '')
            message = "This data is unsaved. Are you certain that you want to cancel?";

        if (isFormDirty($(this)))
            isUnload = confirm(message);

        if (isUnload)
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Of course I can't bind the `beforeunload` event to a `form`... only the `window`, can I get some clues on how I would go about doing this?

The expected result is that when the `form` gets unloaded by whatever means except submission, with dirty inputs that a confirmation appears if they really want to do so.

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: my first thought was to make required changes in your so called *home-brew, spa-like engine* - home-brew suggests you have the "source" code - i.e. not minified or uglified or obfuscated

Comment: See edit for expected result and I am able to modify the homebrew engine.

Comment: What is definition of "unloaded" within context of Question?

Comment: unloaded = removed from the DOM, or even that the DOM is removed

Comment: You can use `MutationObserver` attached to `<body>`, at `MutationEvent` check if `form` is removed node.

Comment: `MutationObserver` looks interesting, you mind throwing down some code as an example so I can give you proper credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MutationObserver` attached to `<body>` with `childList` option set to `true`, at `MutationEvent`, check if `<form>` is removed node.

```html
<body>
  <form id="form">
    <input>
  </form>
  <script>
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(([{removedNodes}]) => {
      
      if (removedNodes.length) {
        // do stuff if `form` is removed from `document.body`
        checkRemovedNodes: for (const node of removedNodes) {
          if (node === form) {
            console.log(`${node.tagName}#${node.id} removed from document`);
            break checkRemovedNodes;
          }
        }
      }

    });
    // remove `form` from `document` in `3000` milliseconds
    observer.observe(document.body, {
      childList: true
    });

    setTimeout(() => document.body.removeChild(form), 3000);
  </script>
</body>
```